# Short Notice Interview

Tags: interviewing, united-states, company-policy

So I just got offered an interview for a position I applied for, but there's a problem.

My current company requires advance notice if an employee will be absent of 24 hours for any amount of time under 1 day. The interview was set for tomorrow, and although the e-mail asked if I needed to reschedule, I'm hesitant to do that to not seem like I'm uninterested in the position.

I can apply my sick time stating I forgot I had an "appointment" (They don't ask for details), and try to request it that way but it feels dishonest. My boss would give it to me though because we have an easy relationship, and my current position doesn't have any projects that are time sensitive.

**What would be the best avenue to take to balance breaking company policy versus rescheduling or just taking the interview?**

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I was always under the impression that doing that was frowned upon. Is it common and acceptable?

Comment: It's frowned upon, but only if the frowners know about it

Comment: How far is the interview site from your current office? You can probably just take few hours off from your work and make up for the lost time by staying late or coming early in the day. Lot of companies allow that but I can imagine it depends on your job role.  Als to, if you are travelling to a different city, then that may not be an option

Comment: @Anoplexian, You're not a child anymore. If they only gave you one day of notice and you haven't said 'yes' yet, you should reschedule it. Most people who can come to a job interview appointment on a day's notice are usually unemployed. And/or the same goes for taking sick days for interviews, if that's your only option, you take it. You lie. Your employer is not your parent. It's not your friend. If it were up to them, they wouldn't want you to interview with someone else anyway.

Comment: Measuring the pros and cons of violating company policy is something you'll have to do for yourself. That combined with the faulty promise that not being available on zero notice somehow indicates a lack of interest makes this unanswerable.

Comment: " My boss would give it to me though because we have an easy relationship,"

Sounds like you already know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You have three options the way I see it:

1. Ask for a reschedule. IMHO it's inconsiderate for a prospective employer to expect you to be prepared and adjust your schedule for their interview with such short notice. They should be asking "is tomorrow OK for you?", not stating "show up tomorrow." If your request for a reschedule is taken as a lack of interest in the position, you're dealing with someone who has unrealistic expectations. If anything, they should be pleased that you A) want the interview and B) don't want to upset an employer by adhering so strictly to all policies.
2. Just call in "sick." On the grand scale of things that people do that might be "dishonest" in the course of interviewing for a new job, or even doing their normal job (coming back 5 minutes late from lunch, etc.) this is pretty far down. If it puts your mind at ease, label it a "mental health day" because, in a way it is - you're expecting this new job to make you happier than the current one does.
3. Forget the whole thing. But you probably don't want to do that since you're the one who sought out the job posting, not the other way around.